# How to apply class to an external component that does not support className?

Tags: reactjs

In my React project I am using a library of components:

```
<customcomponent />
```

However that library components does not support passing className. Therefore I can not use this method to apply style to the component like this:

```
<customcomponent className='mystyles' />
```

How to apply style to the component in such circumstance?

Comment: What library is in question here? If the API does not include this you can style it via classes, but that may be a bit hacky, that means that that component is not intended to be styled. In that case you can try and post on that github as issue to add that ability. But in a lot of cases components encapsulates classes and adds that unique hash in runtime

Comment: A good example is Material-UI where you can assign your class for predefined component classes e.g. `root`. But you can share here what library you are trying to style for more clarification

Comment: You will need to include an example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a wrapper component that wraps your component with a div that accepts a `className`.

```
const DoesntSupportClassNameWrapper = (props) => {
  const { className, style, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <div className={className} style={style}>
      <DoesntSupportClassName {...rest} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

## Full example

<kbd>[Edit @ CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-name-and-style-wrapper-hgi5y?file=/src/App.jsx:0-981)</kbd>

### App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { DoesntSupportClassName, SupportsClassName } from "./components";
import "./styles.css";

const styles = {
  heading: {
    color: "red"
  }
};

const DoesntSupportClassNameWrapper = (props) => {
  const { className, style, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <div className={className} style={style}>
      <DoesntSupportClassName {...rest} />
    </div>
  );
};

DoesntSupportClassNameWrapper.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  style: PropTypes.object
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SupportsClassName text="Heading 1" className="heading" />
      <DoesntSupportClassName
        text="Heading 2"
        className="heading"
        style={styles.heading}
      />
      <DoesntSupportClassNameWrapper text="Heading 3" className="heading" />
      <DoesntSupportClassNameWrapper text="Heading 4" style={styles.heading} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### DoesntSupportClassName.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const DoesntSupportClassName = (props) => {
  const { text } = props;
  return <h1>{text}</h1>;
};

DoesntSupportClassName.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string
};

export default DoesntSupportClassName;
```

### SupportsClassName.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const SupportsClassName = (props) => {
  const { text, className } = props;
  return <h1 className={className}>{text}</h1>;
};

SupportsClassName.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  text: PropTypes.string
};

export default SupportsClassName;
```